# SwiftUI method for performing an action on touch

Tags: swiftui

I'm looking for something like [tapAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/rectangle/3286825-tapaction) for Rectangle, but instead of performing an action on a tap, I'm looking to do it when the view is simply touched.

The case is: I have 3 rectangles in a horizontal line. I want to touch down on rectangle #1, swipe across #2 to land on #3. I want this swipe to trigger an action on rectangle #2.

```
⬛ ⬛ ⬛
------->
```

Is there a siwftui solution for it, or do I need to involve uikit?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create gesture for this

```
private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 10, coordinateSpace: .global)
      .onChanged { print("Changed \($0.location)") }
      .onEnded { print("Changed \($0.location)") }
  }
```

And add to the view:

```
Text("Text")
    .gesture(dragGesture)
```

Read more about available gestures [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures)

**UPD:**
To track gesture changes you need to use `@State` property

```
 @State var position: CGPoint
```

And add to your view position modifier so your view declaration will be the next:

```
  Text("Text")
    .position(position)
    .gesture(dragGesture)
```

**UPD 2:** You can read about available gestures and how to use them [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gestures)

Comment: Thanks! I have DragGesture set up, it acts on the view that it's initiated on, but not on the second view that I'm just swiping over. But I think building my own gesture might be something to look into; thanks for the hint.

Comment: @DenFav did you figure out a solution to this challenge? You know, responding to the fist touch, but not the pan across?

Comment: @user3069232 Don't understand your question

Comment: @DenFav I am sorry, I was asking about touch and SwiftUI.

Comment: @thekodols did you find a solution to this question?

Comment: @user3069232 I suggest the TapGesture can help you. You can use it in the same way as in the example from my answer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tapgesture